# Shortcuts on watch always request access to my app on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, sirikit

I have a swift project with two apps - for iOS and watchOS respectively. The iOS app has more intents for sirikit. One sirikit intent i have only on the iOS in order to use it in a shortcut, run that shortcut from watch, and get something done in my iOS app.

The problem is, when i run that shortcut on apple watch, this shortcut always request access to my app. After given the permission, i get thing worked on my app in iOS. But, when i run this shortcut again on the watch, it request the access to my app on iOS again.

I get problem solved only if i remove my app from the watch side. But, that is not what i want, since i need my app on the watch too, as it has some intents, that should be performed on the watch app's side. I know, that this is an iOS bug beginning from iOS 15, but i don't hope, that apple will ever fix this, as the current version is 16.6, and nothing fixed yet.

Might be anyone has some salvation for that problem, some play around with a targets, or, might be, there is some setting in the intent file, that would get me rid from this problem.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried removing both apps from iOS and watchOS, and build the project again - nothing, the same result. Only after deleting app from the watch side, shortcuts stops asking access to my iOS app after i gave it access once (given permission once, it stops asking). But i need both apps. Intents of the watch app are working well, so, there is no any bugs there.

I have seen, that people had struggle with some smartthings apps (which are also have apps for iOS and watchOS), homekit, and so on. And some developers of these apps had done something, that people had stopped experiencing such a problem.

The watchconnectivity is not an option, since i couldn't get it work if my iOS app is not running. If watchconnectivity would work as a sirikit intent for iOS app, which quickly gets triggered, and runs iOS app from shortcut on the watch, that would be the nice for watchconnectivity, but it seams impossible.